# Cell fracture nothing happening ; Breaking apart an object

Tags: cell-fracture

I'm following a tutorial that has used the annotation tool to mark around the cube so as to guide on where the cell fracture should be concentrated at most. But nothing is happening on my end despite doing the exact same steps, * Mark around the cube  > *Apply the cell fracture with his exact settings.

Could anyone kindly help me understand why nothing is happening

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you haven't actually got your cube selected!

Select it first, then use the cell fracture operation. You may not be able to do this with the pencil tool selected, so switch to a selection tool first.

As an aside: I always thought it was better to add dots with varying density with the annotations rather than scribble on the object, but I could be wrong:

[image]

Looking closer at this screenshot I took, the one line where I accidentally (hurriedly) drew a longer stroke (as opposed to a dot) actually created a high concentration of cracks. Something to bear in mind.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hadn't selected the object. And you're right, adding dots with varying density is actually a lot better in terms of look and controlling how/where I want the cell fractures to be, thank you once again!